# Can one use a 2nd external monitor together with the new iMac 5k?

Tags: imac, display

Sometimes I like to have monitoring data to be displayed on an external monitor to be less 'in my face', even so I would have place for it on my main screen. So, is it possible to attach an external monitor to the new iMac 5k?

And can somebody with powers maybe generate a new tag iMac5k, if it is considered useful?

Comment: where did you look up ?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i looked at Apple specs but was confused with the issue that the iMac does not work as external monitor itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to Apple's website, under the device's "Connections and Expansion" section:

> Headphone port
>   SDXC card slot
>   Four USB 3 ports (compatible with USB 2)
>   Two Thunderbolt 2 ports
>   **Mini DisplayPort output
>
>   Support for DVI, VGA, and dual-link DVI (adapters sold separately)**
>   10/100/1000BASE-T Gigabit Ethernet (RJ-45 connector)
>   Kensington lock slot

[iMac with 5K retina display specs](http://www.apple.com/imac-with-retina/specs/)

Answer (score 1):

I know there's an accepted answer, but I'm running a BenQ GW27605HS as a second monitor via a Thunderbird -> HDMI adapter and works great.  There seems to be a Yosemite bug (ANOTHER Yosemite bug) where the screens will always start up mirrored, but a visit to the system prefs quickly fixes it.

Btw, I would definitely upgrade to the faster graphics card if you're going to do this -- I'd do it anyway with the 5K display but especially if you're going to use an additional monitor.